# Changing a canvas color using textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a `Canvas` where the colors can be changed using three textboxes: R, G and B. The canvas color needs to change whenever the value in a `TextBox` changes.  The `TextBox` is limited to integers between 0 and 255, and as long as a valid number has been entered, I need to change the `Canvas` color.

I know that the `Canvas` background is set via a `SolidColorBrush`, but I do not know how to create a `SolidColorBrush` from an arbitrary collection of RGB values.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for [SolidColorBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush(v=vs.110).aspx). There is a constructor that takes a `Color`, you can create a color via the static method [Color.FromRgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb(v=vs.110).aspx). That should show you where to start with it.  Remember MSDN docs are your friend. Read the docs, look at the examples, that will help you.

Comment: I have edited your question to try to clarify what you are asking. I am not sure if I have edited appropriately so please check it and modify it if I have understood it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three text boxes, I will assume you can pull the text from those and can parse it into the appropriate byte values.  Assuming you have three bytes: r,g,b - then you can create a `SolidColorBrush` with this line of code, which uses the [Color.FromRgb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb(v=vs.110).aspx) static method to create the color from the three values from your textboxes:

```
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r,g,b));
```

Comment: Thank you that helped, apparently I needed to first create the shape and then add the parameters which I can then call from the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r,g,b));` and set the color of your canvas to this property.

Comment: Deleted previous comment because I think I was unclear - You have posted an answer using a `System.Drawing.Color`, but the question is about a WPF `Canvas` which would use `System.Windows.Media.Color`.

Comment: Yes - because `System.Drawing.Color` and `System.Windows.Media.Color` are different.  You cannot create a `System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush` with a `System.Drawing.Color` The WPF [Canvas.Background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.background(v=vs.110).aspx) takes a `System.Windows.Media.Brush`

Comment: I edited, and thanks. I did not notice. I upvoted your answer

Comment: You were not the only one, its why I ended up posting an answer because there was another answer that suggested using the `System.Drawing` colors.